# What are the rules for approving edits?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I was reading a question, and was going to edit just to format some code. Normally this causes no problem, but someone else had already done this.

I approved the edit, but could not edit as it needed one more approval!

I can neither edit or approve a simple edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were going to edit something else, you should have chosen the "Improve Edit" option (or "Reject and Edit" if you wanted to overwrite the suggested edit). This would allow you to format the code and the edit would instantly go through.

Approving always requires another vote, to prevent misclicks and "robo-reviews".

Since you have already voted, you can either wait for another approver / two rejectors, or, if you believe the edit is urgent for some reason, you could edit the post right away (just go to the revisions and click edit on the last entry), but this would reject the suggested edit as conflicting (this applies only to such cases when the edit is to be rejected - it would be unfair to "bury" a good edit).

Comment: The edit was a very simple code formatting change, identical to what I would have done. Having to "Improve Edit" is counter-intuitive, but I will next time.